# How to Show interstitial Ad on every 3 clicks in Android using LibGDX gaming framework

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

How i can show interstitial ad in every 3 button clicks.
Here in my game I've interstitial show in RESTART button

Here is the code

In core module ...MAIN.java and layout main

```
@Override
public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);

    if (((Act) event.getTarget()).enabled) {
       if (event.getTarget().getName().equals("btnRestart")) {
            loadScreen("game");
            // show AdMob Interstitial
            nativePlatform.admobInterstitial();
            return;
       }
    ....
    }
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/admob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/adMob_banner"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"/>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/app"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

there is no btn in layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a static counter .

```
public static int counter=0;
```

Increase that counter on every click of your restart button. Use the `remainder/modulus` operator `%` to get your desired result.

```
if (((Act) event.getTarget()).enabled) {
     if (event.getTarget().getName().equals("btnRestart")) {
            counter++;
            loadScreen("game");
            // show AdMob Interstitial
            if(counter%3==0) 
              nativePlatform.admobInterstitial();
            return;
     }
    ....
}
```